Abbreviating "pixels", according to Chicago Manual of Style: With or without a period?
Should I abbreviate pixels as px or as px. instead, according to Chicago Manual of Style?

The Chicago Manual of Style doesn't explicitly address pixel, but there are some guidelines that apply:

While commonly abbreviations that end in a lowercase letter are written with a period (10.4), for technical abbreviations, periods are omitted (10.49).
The plural of technical abbreviations is formed without an s – px can stand for "pixel" as well as "pixels" (10.49).
In the body text (i.e. outside of tables, notes, parenthetical references etc.), introduce the abbreviation ("...pixels (px)..."), because it is non-standardized and uncommon outside a technical context (as a guideline, cm is in Merriam-Webster, px isn't). Only abbreviate it in the body text if it appears five times or more. (10.3)


Here is what The Chicago Manual of Style (17th edition, 2017) says about abbreviating units of measure:

3.27:

Oil on canvas, 45 x 38 cm
Bronze, 49 x 22 x 16 in.



10.52: No periods are used after any of the SI symbols for units.


10.64: In the rare instances in which abbreviations for US units of measure are used in scientific copy, they are usually set without periods; in nonscientific contexts, periods are customary.


10.49: The following list includes some abbreviations used in various branches of the physical and biological sciences and in technical writing. Periods are omitted.

cm centimeter
dpi - dots per inch
GB - gigabyte
ha - hectare
...


It doesn't provide examples for abbrevaiting pixels, but from the excerpts above it seems that pixels should be written without a period, because I don't see how they are different from gigabyte or hectare examples in 10.49.
